# varieties on '*lookups' arguments for the function 'prefetch_related'

Tags: django

I can't figure out the difference between prefetch_related('arg_set') and prefetch_related('arg') .

Sometimes prefetch_related doesn't work when using argument 'arg'even 'arg_set' works.

I've searched through docs.djangoproject.com but, at least, I can't find related document on both pages below.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/ https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/2.1/ref/contrib/contenttypes/

Could some of you elaborate the difference and when _set is necessary?
And I want to read the official document related to this issue so showing me the reference link is appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

environment:
windows10, python 3.7.2, django 2.1.8, sqlite3, PyCham 2019.1 .

views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Article


def index(request):
    a = Article.objects.all().select_related('user').prefetch_related('comment_set').order_by('id')  # [1]
    a = Article.objects.all().select_related('user').prefetch_related('comment').order_by('id')  # [2]

    return render(request,
                  'sns/index.html',
                  {'articles': a})
```

models.py

```py
from django.db import models
from article_comment_model.settings import AUTH_USER_MODEL


class Article(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='article_user')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = models.TextField()


class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comment_user')
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
```

I want to understand the variety of prefetch_related arguments well.

Answer (score 0):

The argument for callig `prefetch_related()` would be the name of the relation. In your case this would be a reverse `ForeignKey` relationship. As you can see in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) the name of the reverse relationship will be `FOO_set` where `FOO` is the model's lowercase name.

Therefore in your example `prefetch_related('comment_set')` should be correct. If you would specify a [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) like

```
article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                            related_name='comments')
```

the `related_name` will get used instead of `FOO_set`, therefore `prefetch_related('comments')` should be valid in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the lookup to use in `prefetch_related` depends on the answer to a couple of questions:

- Is the relation defined on the model you are querying or on the other side of the relationship?

If the relation is defined on the model you are querying (termed "forward relationship" by the Django docs), then the lookup is simply the *field name*. If the relation is defined at the other end of the relationship ("backward relationship"), then the lookup depends on a second question:

- Have you defined a `related_name` in the other model where the relationship is defined?

If yes, the lookup is the `related_name`. If there is no `related_name`, Django uses a default name, which is `modelname_set` for x-to-many relationships and `modelname` for x-to-one relationships (both in lower case).

In practical terms, this means the following in your code:

- x-to-many relationships:

```
# no related names defined, using default manager name
Article.objects.prefetch_related('comment_set')
# using related names
User.objects.prefetch_related('article_user', 'comment_user')
```

- x-to-one relationships:

```
Article.objects.prefetch_related('user')
Comment.objects.prefetch_related('article', 'user')
```

Using `prefetch_related` for x-to-one relationships like in the last two examples above is rare. We mostly use `select_related` as the latter only creates a join in the original query instead of issuing a separate query. However, as you can read towards the end of its [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#s-prefetch-related), `prefetch_related` has a few potential advantages. It can:

- fetch a filtered queryset
- fetch incomplete models (via `only` and `defer`)
- perform nested prefetching via the `Prefetch` object