# Querying Querysets in Django? Attempting to return a step and then the sub-steps underneath it

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-queryset

I'm thinking this is actually really intuitive, but I cannot figure it out.

So I have a model called SWS_Document. Then I have SWS_Document_Step that has a foreign key to SWS_Document. Following that I have a 3rd model SWES_Step which has a foreign key to SWS_Document_Step. Essentially SWES_Document_Step is a sub-step to SWS_Document_Step.

Example. It would be "Mix the butter into the recipe" would be SWS_Document_Step. While SWES_Document_Step__id=1 would be "Place the butter into a microwave safe bowl." SWES_Document_Step__id=2 would be "Microwave the butter for 30 seconds."

Those are sub-steps to "mix the butter into the recipe."

```
class SWS_Document(models.Model):

    machines = models.ManyToManyField(Machine, related_name='SWS_documents')
    document_description = models.CharField(max_length=150, default="")
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class SWS_Document_Step(models.Model):

    STEP_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('People', 'People'),
        ('Quality', 'Quality'),
        ('Velocity', 'Velocity'),
        ('Cost', 'Cost'),
    )
    document_number = models.ForeignKey(SWS_Document, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sws_sequence_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(editable=True, null=True)

class SWES_Step(models.Model):

    STEP_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('People', 'People'),
        ('Quality', 'Quality'),
        ('Velocity', 'Velocity'),
        ('Cost', 'Cost'),
    )
    sws_document_id = models.ForeignKey(SWS_Document_Step, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    swes_description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    swes_step_type = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=STEP_TYPE_CHOICES, blank=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

So in my view.py I have taken swsallsteps.

```
def DocumentView(request, document_id):
    # final goal should be to pass a list full of lists...
    # e.g. [
    #[name1, [hazard1, hazard2], [assessment1, assessment2]],
    #[name2, [hazard3, hazard4], [assessment3, assessment4]],
    #]
    steps = []
    swsallsteps = SWS_Document_Step.objects.filter(document_number=document_id)
    swesallsteps = SWES_Step.objects.filter(sws_document_id=document_id)
    return render(request, 'StandardWorkDocuments/document.html', {
        'swsallsteps': swsallsteps,
        'swesallsteps': swesallsteps,
    })
```

Then in Document.html I have a few for loops.

```
{% for step in swsallsteps %}
    <button class='collapsible'>{{ step.sws_sequence_number }} - {{ step.sws_work_element_description}} - <em><b>{{step.sws_step_type}}</b></em> - published - {{step.pub_date}}</button>
    <div class="content">
        {% for swessteps in swesallsteps %}
            <p>{{swessteps.swes_description}}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Essentially, what I believe I'm trying to get is a queryset in a query. So it would be [[Mix the butter into the recipe, [Place the butter in a microwave safe bowl, microwave the butter for 30 seconds]]

[This is what I'm currently getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pCUg.png)

[This is what I'd hope to get, with a few dumby points put in to show for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VknQb.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can (and should) access nested items via the parent item. The Django documentation has a few useful [examples](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#related-objects) on accessing related objects, and in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55523664/varieties-on-lookups-arguments-for-the-function-prefetch-related/55524064#55524064) you can find a more detailed rundown on accessing related objects; the `related_name` property for instance can replace the `model_set` syntax and help readability (if appropriately chosen).

Your second loop should like this:

```
{% for swes_step in step.swes_step_set.all %}
    <p>{{swes_step.swes_description}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

You are now accessing the second step level not from a separate queryset but from the parent step. You can scrap the second queryset (`swesallsteps`).

To avoid issuing multitudes of database queries, you should use `prefetch_related` to get all data in as few steps as possible:

```
swsallsteps = (SWS_Document_Step.objects
    .filter(document_number=document_id)
    .prefetch_related('swes_step_set')
)
```

Comment: where did you get the swes_step_set? Is the '_set' portion of that added onto the model of "swes_step"

essentially, "Model" + "_set"? or am I missing something?

Comment: Well spotted, this is how you access an x-to-many relationship that is defined on the other model. See the link in the updated answer.

Comment: So, "_set" is a part of the object oriented programming of what you can do to a query?

What if I'm trying to get the related information of SWES_Step? Because I have related information there too.